# Content Assist in Android studio with C\C++ is not working

Tags: c++, android-studio, android-ndk

I have Android Studio 2.1.2, Android SDK 25, Andriod Ndk 11. Project starts and compiles well from Android Studio, but I couldn't use IDE, cause there is no Content Assist - ctrl+space and ctrl+click is not working in C\C++ sources for include and functions, the only message is - "cannot find declaration to go to" like here:

[image: error image]

Somebody know how to solve the problem? For java sources everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

- First Install the NDK bundle from Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager
- Import the hello-jn sample using File -> Import Sample (Note: This sample is using the new gradle-experimental plugin)
- Click Run -> Edit Configurations... and and a new Android Native configuration
- Run and Debug Your App

Comment: I do not understand how it can help, but I'll try. Gradle plugin couldn't help eclipse.

Comment: I just upgraded Android Studio to 2.2 and it works: ctrl+left click, syntax checnking, etc. But by default project builds with cmake(CLakeList.txt), previously with Android.mk. But this is different story.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem! My solution is to re-set NDK path in "local.properties".

When i use default ndk path (ex: ndk.dir=C:\Users\%user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle sdk.dir=C:\Users\%user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk ) , I will have the same problem. So I download other NDK (from google official web-site) ,and set "ndk.dir", and I sloved.

You can try it~ maybe helpful for you.

ps. I use NDK version:14 , will happen this. I use v13 or v12 will solved.